# Sending sssd.log to syslog

Tags: logging, syslog

How do I configure SSSD to send sssd.log logs to syslog? I would like to include the DEBUB SSSD logs as well. We would like to feed the sssd logs to Splunk. Our systems are already configured to send syslog to Splunk Security Module. So we would like to use that setup, instead of the Splunk Forwarder.

Comment: Why don't you use Splunk forwarder to send the logs from file directly?

Comment: @heemayl, we systems are already configured to send syslog to Splunk Security Module. So we would like to use that setup, instead of the Splunk Forwarder.